# Microsoft teams connect with freeswitch

Tags: ssl, microsoft-teams, freeswitch

I have configure the fqdn domain for the direct routing with the freeswitch but in that my tls connectivity status is not activating and also error showing in network effectiveness so how can connect the my domain with tls.[image: sbc configuration page]

This status should be active and my sbc should work with the freeswitch.